# Regex from the first slash to the slash after hashtag

Tags: javascript, url

I have multiple urls:

```
https://www.blablabla.com/one/two/?landingPageType=PASSENGER&locale=es_ES&mktport[…]eItineraryKey=99,1A&segmentKey0=0,UX6012&segmentKey1=0,UX6079#details/11723993857/

https://www.blablabla.com/foo/bar/test/#test_a

https://www.blablabla.com/foo/bar/test/#test_a/45345/43
```

I need to get from the first slash to the slash after hashtag like:

```
/one/two/#details
/foo/bar/test/#test_a
/foo/bar/test/#test_a
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks @markalex and if I need to ignore the query params?

Comment: Sorry, misread expected output for first input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily parse the urls via the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.blablabla.com/foo/bar/test/#test_a/45345/43');

const path = url.pathname;
const hash = url.hash.split('/')[0];

console.log(path + hash);
```